# How to make a math.random into a for loop

Tags: java, for-loop, random

in short form, i created a math.random that will choose a random number, then another variable later will use that number. After that random is used math.random will choose another number, and this would go on forever. I would think to use a for loop with the math.random making it look something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i <100; i++) {
    int mRandom = (int) (Math.random() * 21 + 15);
}
```

then later I use the number to change the speed and angle of the sprite i created (this entire code is used to create the sprite so I don't have a problem with the sprite being used)

```
   for (int i = mIDontKnowTimer; i == mRandom; i++) {
```

here I have a timer that i already created, and when that timer is equal to the number generated by mrandom the speed and angle changes

```
        int pSpeed = (int) (Math.random() * 3 + 3);
        int pAngle = (int) (Math.random() * 359);

        mXSpeed = pSpeed * Math.cos(pAngle);
        mYSpeed = pSpeed * Math.sin(pAngle);
    }
```

Im confused as to how to make the mRandom a loop, because it is saying the first line has an illegal start of type and that it can't find "i" in the code

Comment: Can you try rephrasing your question? I don't follow.

Comment: The code you have written would compile but does nothing. Can you clarify your question a little bit or provide more context?

Comment: What is the exact error? Do you already have a variable named `i`?

Comment: Your question is still a little unclear, are you trying to write a nested for loop that iterates up to the random number `mRandom`?

Comment: that is exactly correct user1875195

Answer (score 0):

I'd first put Math.Random into a function and call it in my main loop.

```
public static int randomNumberGenerator(int min, int max){
        Random rand = new Random();
        return rand.nextInt(max - min) +min;

    }
```

Now call it within a `for/while` loop.

Answer (score 0):

*As written*, your `mRandom` is only valid within the scope of the first `for` loop, and will be completely unavailable to your second `for` loop. (I say "as written" because I suspect your code doesn't actually look like this - it would fail to compile.)

Your second loop isn't particularly clear to me, but it looks like you're trying to change your sprite's direction and speed `mRandom` times? (Edit: comments confirm this.)

You could just use a nested `for` loop to accomplish this:

```
int mRandom;
int pSpeed, pAngle;

for (int i = 0; i <100; i++) { //100 times in a row,
    mRandom = (int) (Math.random() * 21 + 15); //generate a random number

    for (int j = 0; j < mRandom; j++) { //count up to that random number
        //and repeatedly adjust your sprite's properties
        pSpeed = (int) (Math.random() * 3 + 3);
        pAngle = (int) (Math.random() * 359);

        mXSpeed = pSpeed * Math.cos(pAngle);
        mYSpeed = pSpeed * Math.sin(pAngle);
    }
}
```

It's worth noting that, unless you're redrawing your sprite somewhere in there, the extra speed and angle changes will be meaningless - you're updating those properties multiple times but only redrawing once, so only the most recent change will stick.

Comment: why would it fail to compile?

Comment: Your code appears to have two separate for loops, with `mRandom` declared within the body of the first. That means it's only valid within the body of the first, and will go back out of scope before the second loop begins.

Comment: My code does work around it, simply by declaring `mRandom` outside the loop. This keeps it within scope for the duration of the loops. Declaring it within the outer loop would also make it visible within the inner loop, although I find that less clean.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying to do this

```
for (int i = 0; i <100; i++) {
    int mRandom = (int) (Math.random() * 21 + 15);

    for (int i = mIDontKnowTimer; i == mRandom; i++) {
        ....
    }
}
```

The issue you are seeing is that you were trying to access the mRandom variable outside of it's scope.

Comment: This was the first thing I tried doing, but when I start up my game the sprite shudders around for half a second then goes on with one speed and angle for the rest of the game